# Google Map addMarker() take some time to show marker.

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In Google Map i want to show multiple markers round 10-15 markers but these marker take some time to show on map.Please take a look on my code

```
 Bitmap markerBitmap;
    Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(R.drawable.marker_icon)
     .resize(markerSize, markerSize)
     .into(new Target() {
        @Override
       public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
          markerBitmap=bitmap;
        }

     @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
      }

      @Override
     public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
     }
     });

for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
 MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
 markerOptions.position(latLng);
 markerOptions.rotation((float) bearing);
 markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerBitmap));
map.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```

Comment: I doubt that'll even work. IIRC, anonymous classes such as your `Target` are forbidden from accessing outside non-final variables, and obviously `markerBitmap` is not one of those. So it might be the case of your markers appearing quicker than you think, but not having any icon in the process.

Comment: What's even more likely is this code snippet doesn't actually compile.

Comment: Picasso callback call on onMapready() and loopt to show marker code run after onMapReady().

Comment: That still doesn't guarantee that request for image load would be done by the time loop is entered. And please format your code to show what it actually looks like, and where these parts are located.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a "sequence of events" problem.

You open a request to load image from resource, then when the resource loading ends, you set a BitmapMarker (I don't know how you do this, any object that enters an anonoymous inner class must be final and can't be changed).

After the creation of the request, you try to create 10 markers. (regardless of whether the request ended or not)

The solution may be to postpone adding marker to when the request ends. You are encouraged to read about functional programming to understand why.

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
.load(R.drawable.marker_icon)
 .resize(markerSize, markerSize)
 .into(new Target() {
    @Override
   public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
     Bitmap markerBitmap;
     markerBitmap=bitmap;

     for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
         MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
         markerOptions.position(latLng);
         markerOptions.rotation((float) bearing);
         markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerBitmap));
     map.addMarker(markerOptions);
       }
    }

 @Override
public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
  }

  @Override
 public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround that solved my problem.

```
 @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            if(googleMap!=null){
                Picasso.with(getContext())
                        .load(R.drawable.marker_icon)
                        .resize(markerSize, markerSize)
                        .into(new Target() {
                            @Override
                            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                                Bitmap markerBitmap;

                                markerBitmap=bitmap;

                                for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
                                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                                    markerOptions.rotation((float) bearing);
                                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerBitmap));
                                    map.addMarker(markerOptions);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                            }
                        });

            }
        }
```